# graphene schema for query input is list of dictionary / object

Tags: graphene-python, flask-graphql

My query input is something like:

```
[{name: "joe", age: 20}, {name: "bob", age: 30}]
```

Then I use a resolver to return something similar like:

```
[{name: "joe", age: 20}, {name: "bob", age: 30}, {name: "jane", age: 21}]
```

Suppose I don't change the dataset, so no need to use mutate.

I am using `flask_graphql` and `graphene`

What's the better way to implement this? (I mean how to build the schema) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure on use case but [GenericScalar](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/blob/master/graphene/types/generic.py) might help.

```
data = graphene.GenericScalar()
```

In mutation, this won't have any specific schema though. Input can accept any structure.